# Can not connect to HTTPS on a server via VPN

Tags: ssl, https, connection, vpn

I have a server at home and another on a VPS hosting. I tried to create L2TP/IPsec tunnel between them. The tunnel works and one server can access HTTP services from the other server (VPS server is client and server at home is VPN server to which I am connecting and runs HTTP and HTTPS services that I am trying to access from VPS server). But when I try to connect via HTTPS, the connection does not work.

This is what happens when I run this command from the remote server connected to the other one via L2TP/IPsec: **openssl s_client -connect SERVER:443**:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

And if I try **wget --verbose https://SERVER/**:

```
Resolving SERVER (SERVER)... SERVERIP
Connecting to SERVER (SERVER)|SERVERIP|:443... connected.
```

So the connection is started, but no data is exchanged. I have tested with nmap and the port is detected as open.

I tried to connect to this VPN via my laptop and from there, I can access both HTTP and HTTPS services, but from this server, I can only use HTTP. I have tried turning off all firewalls that are on the path of the packets but the problem persists.

I know this is a very specific case so if there is no actual answer to what the problem might be, I am at least looking for guidelines to how to debug this as wget, curl and openssl s_clinent don't provide me any details as they stay on the connection established state.

UPDATE: I have opened 443 port on NAT on the home server and tried to connect to HTTPS service directly from VPS server without VPN and it worked. So only when I access HTTPS via VPN, the connection does not work.

Comment: I have asked this question on server fault and my question was put on hold just because it was put as offtopic. Please advise me where is the correct place to ask such questions then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the MTU setting of the L2TP connection. I had to lower the MTU to 1300 as HTTPS + IPSec add so much overhead that the packet was over 1500, which is the upper limit of the Ethernet and SSL packages set DF (Do not fragment) flag on Layer 3 which disables package fragmentation.

Normally, the server would send special ICMP message to notify the VPN server about this problem but I had ICMP blocked by the firewall so there was no error, just connection was not able to establish as packages had too big size and were just dropped.